# Websockets - chrome and firefox differences?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, firefox, websocket

On my site I am using `wss://` protocol for chat etc.

When I connect to my site through Chrome, everything works just fine. But if I use Firefox, it disconnects after few minutes. Client code for both browsers is the same, so why is Firefox behaving that way?

Comment: Can you provide any output from the browser console? Does `onclose` or `onerror` provide any insight into the problem? What versions of the browsers are you using?

Answer (score 3):

The Firefox defaults are:

- network.websocket.max-connections: 200
- network.websocket.timeout.close: 20
- network.websocket.timeout.open: 20
- network.websocket.timeout.ping.request: 10
- network.websocket.timeout.ping.response: 10

The Chromium defaults are listed in the following Chrome URL:

chrome://net-internals/#sockets

**References**

- [about:config Entries](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config_entries)
- [Network Stack Objectives](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/network-stack-objectives)
- [Chromium Source: URL Constants](https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/url_constants.cc?revision=HEAD)
- [Webkit 2 Source: FeatureDefines.xcconfig](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebKit2/Configurations/FeatureDefines.xcconfig)
- [Chromium Source: Content Switches](http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/content/public/common/content_switches.cc)